# Jenkins Active Choices Parameter Groovy Script Does not Run in Restricted Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use the Active Choices Reference Parameter plugin in Jenkins to generate a list of AWS Lambda Functions that the user can select as a parameter. The Groovy script that is provided references the name of an AWS account that the user initially selects, runs the 'aws sts assume-role' command to swap into the given account, and then returns a filtered list of lambda function names from there.

My organization does not allow the jenkins-leader IAM role to assume-role into another account. Only the jenkins-follower IAM role has permission to do so. Because of this, I am required to restrict my project to only run on a specific set of nodes. I am using the "Restrict where this project can run" option within the Freestyle job configuration settings to achieve this (with a proper label given). However, when I run the "aws sts get-caller-identity" command, it shows the current IAM role is set to jenkins-leader, and I cannot run "assume-role".

Would anyone be able to confirm why the Active Choices Reference Parameter plugin does not recognize the restricted label that I provided? I cannot seem to find a clear answer for this within the documentation, or elsewhere online.

I have tried using the "Restrict where this project can run" option to force the Jenkins Job to execute on a specific jenkins-follower node that has the proper IAM role permissions that I am looking for.

I am expecting the "aws sts get-caller-identity" command to return caller identity info that matches with the restricted node that I defined within the Freestyle Job settings. Instead, it is returning identity info for the jenkins-leader node.

I have tested my groovy script on the follower node's Script console, and it returns the info that I expect. However, using the same script on leader node's Script console gives me a permission error (which is also what I expected).

Answer (score 0):

The Active Choices plugin executes its groovy scripts on the controller, regardless of where the job itself is executing. The groovy script could execute a command on an agent using `ssh`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the response on this, I appreciate the clarification. Would you mind giving a quick example on how to target an agent using ssh within a groovy file? I understand that you can do so within a jenkinsfile, but when I use the node() format within the active traces plugin, it seems to throw an error.

Comment: Jenkins steps are not available in these scripts, you have to go down to what Groovy itself supports - executing command as a command-line process. See docs here https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute()
So something like `def stdout = 'ssh agent_host_name command'.execute().text`